# Loading text into a single String

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a Java String from the contents of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

I'm stuck with the problem of loading a whole file(which is a .html file) to a single String.

I'm trying to print the contents which between `<body>` and `</body>`. however; when i run my code, it cannot write anything in to input file. i believe the problem is there is no `<body>` or `</body>` tags in my first line, which means the indexOf() method will return a -1, therefore the whole problem cannot be achieve.  Someone told me should load the whole .html which contains a lot of lines to a single string, i believe he means to load in one line. I  DO NOT KNOW HOW TO DO IT...

here is my code:

```
PrintWriter pr;
try{
  c = new Scanner(f);
pr = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(o));
while (c.hasNextLine()){
  String text = c.nextLine();
    String index = "<body>";
    String index2 = "</body>";
    int i1 = text.indexOf(index);
    int i2 = text.indexOf(index2);
    text = text.substring(i1+6,i2);
    System.out.println("here it is");
    pr.println(text);
    System.out.println("you did !!!");
    pr.flush();}
}catch(Exception e){}
```

}

Comment: thanks. but in fact i don't know how to use Buffer() method..

Comment: You can't cut & paste that code and see if it gets you a String?

Comment: there are many unknown methods and classs in theses solutions.. sorry

Comment: @leohu: Then I suggest you learn about them...

Comment: uhu.....  is that better to use Buffer method to read and write content instead of PrinteWriter and FileoutputStream???

Comment: throw exception in catch block to see whats happening.

Comment: wit's that mean?  u mean I should change  catch(Exception e) to ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Here is a small sample to help you start.

This will work will a simple HTML page.
But for complex pages (with embedded CSS etc) you will have to figure how to find the start/end of body.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("theFile.html");     
byte[] data = new byte[fin.available()];    
fin.read(data);  
String htmlFile = new String(data);  
int start = htmlFile.indexOf("<body>");  
if(start != -1){   
  int end = html.indexOf("</body");  
  if(end != -1){  

     System.out.println("Body is: html.substring(start + 6, end));  
   }  
 }
```